# For 服, how do clothes semantically appertain its verbal meanings 'serve', 'obey', 'convince'?

Tags: etymology

What semantic notions underlie definitions B3-B5 below? [CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%9C%8D) doesn't expatiate the semantic shifts.

[image]

*Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) pp 222-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right part "" means obey, it looks like a person do some work, and it's the original character,
some years later, add "舟" to the left of "", means a person walk lean on a boat, then some years later, "舟" become "月",
And, clothes serves body.

Answer (score 0):

服 (n): clothes

服 (v): to wear

To wear something --> to be confined in it --> to serve; to abide by (obey); to be convinced

Comment: Is this answer based on historical linguistic data, or on personal understanding?